# OpenShift cron does not run

Tags: redhat, cron, openshift-online-2

I have the following file

```
[subdomain.rhcloud.com minutely]\> pwd
/var/lib/openshift/username/app-root/repo/.openshift/cron/minutely
[subdomain.rhcloud.com minutely]\> ls -lha
total 4.0K
drwx------. 2 username username 24 Nov 20 21:08 .
drwx------. 3 username username 21 Nov 20 20:46 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 username username 73 Nov 20 20:54 ticktock.sh
[subdomain.rhcloud.com minutely]\> cat ticktock.sh
*/1 * * * * username php ../../../cron/status.cron.php

[subdomain.rhcloud.com minutely]\> php ../../../cron/status.cron.php
[subdomain.rhcloud.com minutely]\>
```

as shown, the contents of the file execute fine. the file permissions seem right. but the *Cron 1.4* cartridge doesn't seem to fire ticktock.sh.

So I tried to invoke it manually:

```
[subdomain.rhcloud.com minutely]\> ./ticktock.sh
./ticktock.sh: line 1: */1: No such file or directory
```

It tells me the file that exists there doesn't exist.

So I tried the full path to php,

```
[subdomain.rhcloud.com minutely]\> /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2014 05:04:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

and ticktock.sh became

```
[subdomain.rhcloud.com minutely]\> cat ticktock.sh
*/1 * * * * 546e69f54382ec6013000027 /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php ../../../cron/status.cron.php
```

but it still doesn't execute, via cron or command line

```
[subdomain.rhcloud.com minutely]\> ./ticktock.sh
./ticktock.sh: line 1: */1: No such file or directory
```

**What am I missing here?!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenShift cron directories are meant to contain *the actual scripts to be run*, not traditional crontab-style entries.

So you should instead write a simple script to call your PHP code.

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php ../../../cron/status.cron.php
```